# Figures numbering locally

Tags: floats, numbering

I have chosen the chapter numbering for the figures but at some figures 
which I have it all in the same `\begin{figure}` environment using the `\begin{minipage}` environment, i prefer different numbering. So for example i will try to explain with an example:

```
figure 3.1
figure 3.2
figure 3.3.1
figure 3.3.2
figure 3.3.3
figure 3.4
```

In this example figure 3.3.1-3.3.3 is in the same `\begin{figure}` so I prefer the numbering which is shown above, and after that I want to continue with the previous numbering.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I do not want to argue, but are you sure that this is a good idea? Keep in mind the reader: Will he be confused by this numbering?

Comment: Short answer (because of missing MWE): You could use a package like [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). The default would be numbering sub-figures with a, b, c … but you can change it.

Comment: @Jürgen Why you think it is not a good idea ?

Comment: This is perhaps experienced subjectively, but I might feel irritated when the structure of the references changes throughout the text. Please take it just as a remark.

Comment: It should be noted that the subcaption package does not write entries to the lof (it is not a matter of toclevell).